Is there a way to work with FileTables in Entity Framework 6 using DB first approach?
I'm working on a project using .net Framework 4.8 and Entity Framework 6.4.4 (which I might upgrade to 6.5.1), connected to an SQL Server database.
A new requirement has come up where the client wants to upload files and attach them to entities.
After some pretty bad experiences on a different project with a complete separation of the DB and the file system (paths saved to database, files getting moved, DB points to invalid paths etc.), I wanted to go a different route.
After a bit of research, I decided to opt for SQL Server's filetables. Created a filetable as well as a foreign key on an existing table referencing the filetable.
Wanted to update my model from database using edmx - ran into an error saying hierarchyid is not supporter for the target Entity Framework version. Because of this, not only can I not add the foreign key column to my edmx, but I also can't add the filetable at all.
Here is what I'm doing:
I right click inside the edmx diagram -> Update Model from Database -> go to refresh tab -> finish. The property does not get added to the entity, instead, I get the following warning added to the .edmx file above the entity:
<!--Errors Found During Generation:
warning 6005: The data type 'hierarchyid' is currently not supported for the target Entity Framework version; the column 'ForeignKeyColumn' in the table 'DbName.dbo.tableName' was excluded.-->

When I try to add the filetable itself to the edmx diagram via update model from database, the entire entity gets wrapped in a warning comment:
<!--Errors Found During Generation:
warning 6005: The data type 'hierarchyid' is currently not supported for the target Entity Framework version; the column 'parent_path_locator' in the table 'DbName.dbo.Files' was excluded.
warning 6031: The column 'path_locator' on the table/view 'DbName.dbo.Files' was excluded, and is a key column.  The table/view has been excluded.  Please fix the entity in the schema file, and uncomment.
<EntityType Name="Files">
  <Property Name="stream_id" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
  ((other properties, omitted for brevity))
  <Property Name="is_temporary" Type="bit" Nullable="false" />
</EntityType>-->

It's very hard to find information on this, as I need to

filter out all the EF core information, but also
filter out all the code first information.

I'm wondering if there is some kind of workaround for my problem, or if there is some other solution I'm overlooking. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much.

EF6 doesn't support file tables, ef-core doesn't even support it. Look for a non-ef method.
